# Convert Multi-Dimensional Array to Condition Expression in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to convert an array to condition-like expression string that will be used in the [JS Filtrex](https://github.com/joewalnes/filtrex) library. The JS part is irrelevant for this question.

Following is a sample PHP array that I'm trying to work with.

```php
$condition = array(
    'and',
    array(
        array(
            'field' => 'show_image',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => 1
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'or',
        array(
            'field' => 'filter',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'align',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => 'left'
        )
    )
);
```

The resulting string will be something like this :

```
show_image == 1 and ( filter != 1 or align == "left" )
```

I'm not sold on the array structure so you're free to modify the array as long as it can be extended with more conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide different possibilities?

Comment: @vivek_23 https://gist.github.com/jeetsaha/031d6bbcf6e885a76bbe09ac1e631215 will translate to

`grid_enable == 1 and grid_column >= 3 and ( filter != 1 or align == left )`

Comment: And how did you come up with that structure? Seems like it was an AST already designed with a specific implementation in mind.

Comment: @mario Not exactly. I'm creating a complex form system which will contain fields that will be dependent on other fields.

The form's elements and HTML structure is created via a PHP class. I'm currently working on creating an implementation for conditional fields. I'll pass the example array to a method which would then convert it to the desired string and append it to the fields HTML as a data attribute. The data attribute would be parsed using JS and Filtrex library and would automatically show or hide the field based on other form fields.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to recurse such a structure, and switch according to the first element:

- If it's a string, then treat the remaining arguments as operands/expressions, [`join`ed](http://php.net/join) by operator
- For associative arrays, just concat field/compare/value into a string

For example:

```
function join_expr($opts) {
    if (isset($opts["compare"])) {    // optional ↓↓↓ caretaking of value type(!)
        return "($opts[field] $opts[compare] '$opts[value]')";
    }
    elseif (gettype($opts[0]) == "string") {
        $op = array_shift($opts);
        return join(
            " $op ",
            array_map("join_expr", $opts)   // recurse on operands/subexpressions
        );
    }
    elseif (count($opts) == 1) {   // somewhat redundant
        return "(" . join_expr($opts[0]) . ")";
    }
    else {
        trigger_error("wrong struct");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: I tried it but it only results in one layer of condition. What I need is 2 layers. So for example this gist - https://gist.github.com/jeetsaha/031d6bbcf6e885a76bbe09ac1e631215


- outer condition 1
- outer condition 1
---- inner condition 1
---- inner condition 2
- outer condition

Comment: Yeah, that would yield `((grid_enable == '1')) AND ((grid_column >= '3')) AND (filter != '1') OR (align == 'left') AND ((grid_gutter == 'large'))` for above example. Probably should move the parens to the `array_map` section.

Comment: I think I can work with your code. I've removed the parenthesis to the array map section as you've advised and it work in almost most of the cases. And modified the code a bit. It's also very efficient using recursive array map function. 

I think I can work on your code. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it works on all cases, but on yours it works well  ( i guess )

what I advise you is to delete the nested array `$condition[1]` and write directly `$condition[1][0]` array ( the new array structure is in the code below )

```php
<?php

$condition = array(
    'and',
    array(
            'field' => 'show_image',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'or',
        array(
            'field' => 'filter',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'align',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => 'left'
        )
    )
);

function generateExpression( Array $condition ) : String
{
 return $condition['field'] . " " . $condition['compare'] . " " . $condition['value'];
}

function generateConditionExpression ( Array $conditionTree ) : String
{
  if ( array_key_exists("field",$conditionTree)  ) 
  {
     return generateExpression($conditionTree);
  }
  //else
  return "(" . generateConditionExpression( $conditionTree[1] ) . " " . $conditionTree[0] . " " . generateConditionExpression( $conditionTree[2] ) . ")";

}

echo generateConditionExpression($condition);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. 

I need it to work for 2 layers of conditions. See gist - 
https://gist.github.com/jeetsaha/031d6bbcf6e885a76bbe09ac1e631215


So the result will be 

`grid_enable == 1 and grid_column >= 3 and ( filter != 1 or align == left )`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with nested `foreach()`,

```
<?php
$condition = array(
    'AND',
    array(
        array(
            'field' => 'grid_enable',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => 1
        ),
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'field' => 'grid_column',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => 3
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'OR',
        array(
            'field' => 'filter',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'align',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => 'left'
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'field' => 'grid_gutter',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => 'large'
        ),
    ),
);
$final_result = '';
$double = false;
foreach($condition as $k=>$v){
    $result = [];
    if(!is_array($v)){
        $operator_out = $v;
    }else{
        foreach($v as $k1=>$v1){
            if(!is_array($v1)){
                $operator_inn = $v1;
            }else{
                $result[] = implode(' ',array_values($v1));
            }
        }
    }
    if(count($result) == 1){
        if($double){
            $final_result.= " ".$operator_out." ".$result[0];    
        }else{
            $final_result.= $result[0]." ".$operator_out." ";    
        }
    }
    else if(count($result) == 2){
        $final_result.= "(".implode(" $operator_inn " , $result).")";
        $double= true;
    }
}
echo $final_result;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/BWmus

Comment: Thanks man. Real close. I'm running the code on this condition - https://gist.github.com/jeetsaha/031d6bbcf6e885a76bbe09ac1e631215

Your's yield `grid_enable == 1 AND grid_column >= 3 AND (filter != 1 OR align == left)grid_gutter == large OR`

Whereas it should be

`grid_enable == 1 and grid_column >= 3 and ( filter != 1 or align == left ) and grid_gutter == large`

Comment: @JeetSaha let me try bro..I'll get back to you :)

Comment: Thanks. You're free to modify the array structure. It just needs to work with 2 layers of conditions.

Comment: Thanks brother. It works in most cases but fails if there aren't a 2nd layer of condition. @Mario has provided a better solution and it works in all cases. 

Once again thanks a ton for your time. I'm new to this community and have only started out a freelancer but I'm really amazed with the help everyone has provided me. So I'll try to do the same for others. Thanks again.